# Passing props in Styled-Component didn't work(with functional component)

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

Nowadays, I am just getting started learning styled-component. I have no idea why it isn't working what I expected.
First, I pass props a data(weekendData) and I want to change the color depending on the data. If the data.schedule(weekendData.schedule) includes("_") I want to change the color red or not it should be black/blue.

- what I expected

: In weekendData.schedule the sixth element includes "_", so it should be red color but it didn't change anything.
Furthermore, when I change black to another color like pink or yellow, the color is still black which means the default color. I guess the color in the styled-component didn't do anything.

This is weekendData

[image]

This is my code

```
<WeekendScheduleDate value={weekendData}>
  {extractMonthFromWeekendData(0)}/{extractDateFromWeekendData(0)}
</WeekendScheduleDate>
<WeekendScheduleDate value={weekendData}>
  {extractMonthFromWeekendData(1)}/{extractDateFromWeekendData(1)}
</WeekendScheduleDate>
<WeekendScheduleDate value={weekendData}>
  {extractMonthFromWeekendData(2)}/{extractDateFromWeekendData(2)}
</WeekendScheduleDate>
<WeekendScheduleDate value={weekendData}>
  {extractMonthFromWeekendData(3)}/{extractDateFromWeekendData(3)}
</WeekendScheduleDate>
<WeekendScheduleDate value={weekendData}>
  {extractMonthFromWeekendData(4)}/{extractDateFromWeekendData(4)}
</WeekendScheduleDate>
<WeekendScheduleDateSat value={weekendData}>
  {extractMonthFromWeekendData(5)}/{extractDateFromWeekendData(5)}
</WeekendScheduleDateSat>
<WeekendScheduleDateSun>
  {extractMonthFromWeekendData(6)}/{extractDateFromWeekendData(6)}
</WeekendScheduleDateSun>
```

```
const WeekendScheduleDate = styled.span`
  margin-right: 1%;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: ${props =>
    props.weekendData &&
    props.weekendData.schedule.map(obj =>
      obj.includes("_") ? "red" : "black"
    )};
`;

const WeekendScheduleDateSat = styled.span`
  margin-right: 1%;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: ${props =>
    props.weekendData &&
    props.weekendData.schedule.map(obj =>
      obj.includes("_") ? "red" : "blue"
    )};
`;

const WeekendScheduleDateSun = styled.span`
  margin-right: 1%;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: red;
`;
```

Current Result
: from 12/20 to 12/25 black color I guess default color.

I would really appreciate your help!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the prop `value` and not `weekendData` to your styled component. Also, don't do a map inside the styled component. Fetch the value before and pass a simple value.

```js
const WeekendScheduleDate = styled.span`
  margin-right: 1%;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: ${({color}) => color};
`;

const color = weekendData.schedule[0].includes("_") ? "red" : "black";

<WeekendScheduleDate color={color}>
  {extractMonthFromWeekendData(3)}
</WeekendScheduleDate>
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your attention. If I want to pass "weekendData" what should I do?

Comment: I've updated my comment. Making a map on weekendData doesn't make any sense, because you need to retrieve a simple color, not return an array of colors. So, I've checked the color in a const, and then passed a `color` prop to the styled component.